# border fade/scale on click?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've come across an effect I'm trying to replicate using css/javascript, although I'm struggling a little...

Watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXqXpwyBI1k and during the movie, you'll notice that when the presenter presses any of the buttons, a white box zooms and fades into view and then quickly fades back out.

It's very subtle but very effective.

Anyone know of the name of this type of effect, or even has a link to some code that replicates it?

In response to @Fabrizio, this is the code I wrote. As you can see, when I call the animate, the "shadow" button starts from 0,0 width/height and expands to the target width/height.

Another weird thing, is I can't use += or -= on the width/height... I thought it increased/decreated the "current" value, not reset from 0 and started again...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
          var shadow = $('<button class="button shadow">&nbsp;</button>');
          shadow.css({
            width : $(this).outerWidth() + 2,
            height : $(this).outerHeight() + 2,
            marginLeft : '-1px',
            marginTop : '-1px',
            opacity : 0
          });

          $(this).before(shadow);
          shadow.animate({
            opacity : 0.5,
            marginLeft : '-=2',
            marginTop : '-=2',
            width : $(this).outerWidth() + 6,
            height : $(this).outerHeight() + 6
          }, 200);
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      body { padding: 50px; background: #333; }
      .button { padding: 15px 25px; border: 0; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; }
      .button.red { background: #FF0000; color: #FFFFFF; }
      .button.shadow { background: transparent; display: block; position: absolute; border: solid 1px #FFFFFF; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="button red">Test</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you looked into jQuery ? you could generate a div on the fly, position absolute, give the coordinates of the clicked object, and then use animate to make it visible and then disappear. I never done it, but I don't assume being incredibly hard with the help of jQuery

Comment: I have, unfortunately my laptop's a little unwell and as I was getting up to do something, it turned off during some tests. When using the animate functionality to change the width, height and margin's, instead of "zooming", it resized the "shadow" element from 0 to the width/height instead of from incrementing as it should. I will post a sample. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is something I was able to wring in a few minutes.

You can play with the border or the color, please refer to the jQuery animate documentation for more info about the animate (for example you cannot animate the border color unless you use a plugin, nor have a bouncy effect

```
$('.style_logo_position_extra_logo').mouseover(function(){
    $('<div/>')
        .width($(this).outerWidth())
        .height($(this).outerHeight())
        .offset($(this).offset())
        .css({
            'border-width':'2px',
            'border-style':'double',
            'border-color':$(this).css('border-color'),
            'position':'absolute',
            'borderTopLeftRadius': $(this).css('borderTopLeftRadius'), 
            'borderTopRightRadius': $(this).css('borderTopRightRadius'),
            'borderBottomLeftRadius': $(this).css('borderBottomLeftRadius'),
            'borderBottomRightRadius': $(this).css('borderBottomRightRadius'),
            'WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius': $(this).css('WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius'),
            'WebkitBorderTopRightRadius': $(this).css('WebkitBorderTopRightRadius'),
            'WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius': $(this).css('WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius'),
            'WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius': $(this).css('WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius'),
            'MozBorderRadius': $(this).css('MozBorderRadius')
        })
        .appendTo('body')
        .animate({
                'border-width':'6px',
                'opacity':0.25,
                'width':'+=6',  //use even numbers if possible
                'height':'+=6',
                'left':'-=8',   //-((+width/2) + (delta border) +1) = -((+6/2) + (6-2)+1) =-8  
                'top':'-=8',
                'borderTopLeftRadius': '+=6', 
                'borderTopRightRadius': '+=6',
                'borderBottomLeftRadius': '+=6',
                'borderBottomRightRadius': '+=6',
                'WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius': '+=6',
                'WebkitBorderTopRightRadius': '+=6',
                'WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius': '+=6',
                'WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius': '+=6',
                'MozBorderRadius': '+=6'
                },500, 'linear',function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                })
        ;
})
```

I am actually going to use this one on my site

Comment: Looking good. I'm just having a fiddle around with it. I'm hoping the author of  the video is able to share his secret. If so, i'll post it on here also.

Comment: I took Fabrizio's response, simplified it a bit, and made a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/bengundersen/T7u54/